# Expression cannot be used as a function

Tags: c++

On line 23 it' saying expression cannot be used as a function. I'm not understanding what it means. I'm not sure what its asking me to change and would like some help. At first I thought it might have been my predefined M_PI constant in my header that I changed to PI and directly defined it in the code but that didn't work.

```
#include "std_lib_facilities_4.h"
int main() {

    const double PI = 3.141592653589793238463;

    //formula for area of a circle is pi*r^2    
    //area of a 14" circle is 153.94"

    cout << "Enter cord length in inches: \n\n";

    double chord_length;

    while(cin >> chord_length) {

        double radius = 7.0;
        double angle_of_sect = (asin((chord_length / 2.0) / radius)) * 2.0;
        double area_of_sect = (angle_of_sect / 360.0(PI * radius));
        double area_of_seg = area_of_sect - (((chord_length / 2.0) * radius) * 2.0);
        double perc_of_pizza = (100.0 * area_of_seg) / 153.94;


        if(chord_length > 14) {
            cout << "Chord Length Too Long \n";
        } else if(chord_length <= 0) {
            cout << "Chord Length Too Small \n";
        }

        cout << "\nSegment area is equal to: " << perc_of_pizza << ".\n";

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where is line 23 exactly? And can you format your code properly?

Comment: Sorry this was the first time using this website. Line 23 is the double area_of_sect - (angle_of_sect / 360.0(PI * radius));  and the error is pointed at by the compiler to the second to last parenthesis at the end.

Comment: I never understood how "first time using this website" was any excuse for submitting a question with terribly formatted code and insufficient detail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In mathematics, `360.0(PI * radius)` is clearly multiplication.

But in C++ it is just as clearly an attempt to call 360.0 as a function - which is doomed to failure. `a(b)` is always a function call.

You need to be explicit with your operators:

```
360.0 * (PI * radius)
```

Comment: So I would need to define 360 as a double so it wont get mixed up as a function?

Comment: No - you just need to put in the extra `*` as shown. `360.0` is already a `double`.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a `*` sign.

`(angle_of_sect / 360.0(PI * radius));`

should be

`(angle_of_sect / 360.0*(PI * radius));`

It's attempting to call function 360.0 which obviously isn't a function.

Answer (score 0):

In 23, Instead

```
(angle_of_sect / 360.0(PI * radius));
```

will be

```
(angle_of_sect / 360.0*(PI * radius));
```

You forget to give `*` sign.